# Download a txt file using a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to make a html button which downloads a file from a server into the user's machine with a *servlet*. Here is the code:

```
String id_archivo = (request.getParameter("idArchivo") == null) ? "" : request.getParameter("idArchivo");
String nombre_archivo = (request.getParameter("nomArchivo") == null) ? "" : request.getParameter("nomArchivo");

//Para que se baje el archivo
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + nombre_archivo + "\"");

log.info("Buscando archivo nombre[" + nombre_archivo + "] id[" + id_archivo + "]");
byte[] archivo =getFile(id_archivo, nombre_archivo);
response.setContentLength(archivo.length);
ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();

sos.write(archivo);
sos.flush();
sos.close();
```

The problem is that it doesn't download the file, it just shows it in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into the `Content-Disposition` Header. It is explained here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1 - essentially it allows you to specify a "hint" to the browser to handle the file as a download.